# Rails 4 Can't Pass Params from View to Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Course#show view where I'm trying to pass the Course ID to my Order controller.

In my Course#show view I have this:

```
<%= link_to 'Buy', new_purchase_path(params[:id=>@course.id]) %>
```

I've also tried:

```
<%= link_to 'Buy', {:controller => :purchases, :action => :new}, :params => {:id => @course.id} %>
```

Yet, I keep getting the error:

```
Couldn't find Course with 'id'=
```

In the purchases_controller, I have this in new:

```
def new
  @purchase = Purchase.new
  @course = Course.find(params[:id])
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What about `new_purchase_path(@course)` or `new_purchase_path(:id => @course.id)`

Comment: I still get the same issue

Comment: Do you find the record in Rails console, if you manually try to get the Course with this ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass something in link you have to name it.

SO passing just an `id` would look like this:

```
new_purchase_path(id: @course.id)
```

I would pass the course_id:

```
new_purchase_path(course_id: @course.id)
```

Then you would be able to retrieve this from params:

```
params[:course_id]
```